# UV-Vis Absorbance against wavelength graph for finding max wavelength

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

I have plotted the absorbance against wavelength graph to find the optimum wavelength for maximum absorbance of p-nitroaniline. However, the curve (dark blue) of the most concentrated solution (sample 7 - 80.0 x 10^-5 M) looks a bit weird. There are 2 decrease in absorbance at around 350 nm and 370 nm before the maximum absorbance at around 385 nm. p-nitroaniline was diluted with DMSO and it was mixed with enzyme solution in the cuvette to duplicate conditions in the enzyme assay. p-nitroaniline is the product of an enzymatic reaction and there is a second part of the experiment regarding the enzyme reaction kinetics. All the absorbance were measured using UV-Vis spectrometer.

I am guessing if it has anything to do with my blank?  [image]

Comment: A blank would make the same patterns for all samples, not proportional ones as on the plot. The peak may consist of multiple merge peaks. If you measured spectrum in gaseous phase, you would probably see a peak forest.

Comment: If you can, check the manual for the spectrometer to see if there is an automatic switch-over in light sources at 350 nm, i.e., deuterium lamp for wavelengths below 350 nm and tungsten lamp for longer wavelengths.

Comment: @EdV, A good spectrometer should not cause a dip from light switch until and unless the mirrors are messed up, and why there are two dips?

Comment: Joe, What is the wavelength step size and what is your cuvette material? Also, it seems your dips are concentration dependent, do you see any particulates or aggregation?

Comment: @AChem I have seen the switch-over issue before, in a teaching lab instrument. Sadly, teaching instruments can be subjected to hard use or abuse and not maintained properly. No clue about the other dip.

Comment: Don't forget that absorbance $\text{abs} = \log \frac{I_0}{I}$ for incident radiation intensity $I_0$ vs radiation intensity $I$ passing the sample. Thus, with $\text{abs} = 1.0$, there is only 10% remaining, at 1.5 about 3%, and with 1.8 around 1.5%. As a rule of thumb, to stay in the linear range of detectors of (especially) the more affordable UV-Vis spectrometers (teaching lab), it is better to limit the concentration of the sample to the effect to stay below $\text{abs} \approx 1.3$. With multiple solutions of different concentrations, you still can plot $\log{}\epsilon = f(\lambda{})$.

Comment: If the purpose of the exercise was to localize $\lambda$ of maximal $\epsilon$ (e.g., of the sample of $\pu{20E-5 mmol}$, or $\pu{40E-5 mmol}$), than record the spectra multiple times, average the recordings (for better signal/noise ratio) and tap into derivative spectroscopy (was mentioned [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173339/how-can-i-compare-the-uv-vis-absorption-difference-after-metal-ion-chelating-of/173345#173345) w/ link to Agilent); especially the second derivative for its sharp positive-zero-negative transition can be more indicative, than the first derivative.